# For loop output to a list mathematica

Tags: list, loops, for-loop, wolfram-mathematica, output

I can't seem to get the output from this mess into a list, I know the code is poor, but it works. It takes a value from each iteration of the loop, its this output I need as a list. I can do it manually but its a pain with 1000+ values... Thanks in advance for any help.

```
For[r = 1, r <= 5, r++, 

 draws = 1000;
 FredList = 
  Reap[For[i = 1, i <= draws, i++, 
     Sow[RandomSample[Join[Table["a", {16}], Table["b", {16}]], 
       2]]];][[2, 1]];
 tally = Tally[FredList];
 Sort[tally][[All, 2]];
 rules = Rule @@@ tally;
 {{"a", "a"}, {"b", "b"}, {"b", "a"}, {"a", "b"}} /. rules;
  Plotpoints = {{"a", "a"}, {"b", "b"}, {"b", "a"}, {"a", "b"}} /. 
  rules; Print[Plotpoints[[1]]]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of Printing, you can use a Sow and Reap(or other list Tools like AppendTo):

```
Reap[For[r = 1, r <= 5, r++, draws = 1000;
    FredList = Reap[For[i = 1, i <= draws, i++, 
    Sow[RandomSample[Join[Table["a", {16}], Table["b", {16}]],2]]];][[2, 1]];
    tally = Tally[FredList];
    (*Honestly, I don't understand the effect of this Sort here*)Sort[tally][[All, 2]];
    rules = Rule @@@ tally;
    {{"a", "a"}, {"b", "b"}, {"b", "a"}, {"a", "b"}} /. rules;
    Plotpoints = {{"a", "a"}, {"b", "b"}, {"b", "a"}, {"a", "b"}} /.rules;
    Sow[Plotpoints[[1]]]
]][[2, 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `Table` for the outer loop as well.

```
With[{draws = 1000, maxr = 5, 
  pop = Join @@ (ConstantArray[#, 16] & /@ {"a", "b"})}, 
 Table[
  Count[Table[RandomSample[pop, 2], {draws}],
   {"a", "a"}], 
  {maxr}]
 ]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, can you explain what the second line does? Thanks again!

Comment: @User, it generates the list (vector) of 16 "a"s and 16 "b"s.

Comment: my code generates a sequence of a's and b's drawn from a set of 16's and 16b's without replacement for two draws and then replaces the a's and b's and repeats this 1000 times. There is a dependence between the first and second letter drawn, will your code, as it uses randomSample do the same?or is it a random list made from 16's and 16b's ? - sorry if this is tedious, your code is far superior I'm trying to understand it better..

Comment: @user2372443, your code also uses RandomSample. Basically, I just replaced `Join[Table["a", {16}], Table["b", {16}]]` with `pop`, where `pop` is constructed in a similar manner, i.e., a list of 16 "a"s followed by 16 "b"s. The reason why I do it this way, is because your code will generate the same list every time it iterates the inner loop (which is a waste, given that the list is the same). After that, I am taking 2 random choices out of that list, then counting how many times the pair "a","a" came about. I think this is what you are doing in your code. It may not be what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, your code gives very different results to mine when I run it but its much faster.. thanks again for your help

Comment: @user2372443 Sure. Both codes give the same answer (the difference you are finding lies on the Random number generator). Just evaluate `SeedRandom[0]` before running each of the programs and you'll see.